# changed the mule runtime from EE 3.7.0 to CE 3.5.0

Tags: anypoint-studio

I have changed the mule runtime from EE 3.7.0 to CE 3.5.0 but getting error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Application name not specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you still are facing this problem, consider trying these possible solutions:

- Clean your project
- Update the version of the embedded server
- Try creating the application again